# Add custom CSS code for a textbox in form

Tags: theming

The following are the code in my module function for textfield in my form:

```
 $form['price'] = array(
   '#type' => 'textfield',
   '#title' => 'What is Your Price?',
   '#size' => 100,
   '#maxlength' => 10,
   '#required' => TRUE,
  );
```

Now I want to add css for the textbox like I want to add inline code `display:none;` only for the textbox. How can  I do that? Please help.

Comment: Can't you use the default classes generated by drupal?

Comment: I just want to add the inline css.I am not intending to add css class.Like in general I can write the following code `<input type='text' name='abs' style='display:none;'>`. But in Drupal How can I add the **style** part for the text box?

Comment: Did you try adding "element-invisible" class to the form element? Why do you prefer adding only inline styles?

Comment: I want to hide the textbox at first.Then if someone click on a button the textbox will show.thats why I want add a `display:none` for the textbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do it like this:

```
function the_form($form, &$form_state){
     $form['price'] = array(
       '#type' => 'textfield',
       '#title' => 'What is Your Price?',
       '#size' => 100,
       '#maxlength' => 10,
       '#required' => TRUE,
       '#prefix' => '<div style="display:none;">',
       '#suffix' => '</div>',
     );
```